# Adding an extra column and constraint but then when updating the column it fails

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update, sql-server-2014, alter-table

I am attempting to run the following query on SQL Server 2008 in SSMS, however it constantly fails on the third query stating:
Invalid column name 'hasCodeMappingDefaults'.

```
BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [SIntegrationProvider]
ADD [hasCodeMappingDefaults] BIT NULL;
END

BEGIN
ALTER TABLE [SIntegrationProvider]
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_SIntegrationProvider_hasCodeMappingDefaults]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [hasCodeMappingDefaults];
END

BEGIN
UPDATE [SIntegrationProvider]
SET [hasCodeMappingDefaults] = 1
WHERE [provider] = 'EmployeeNavigator';
END
```

When each query is run individually in order they work, I just cannot figure out why I cannot run all three combined (this needs to be done as part of a much larger script being rolled out).

Comment: do you need to commit on every command?

Comment: I thought I needed to execute in the right order and have it compile properly.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I may have found the problem, doing this seems to have resolved the issue:

```
ALTER TABLE [SIntegrationProvider]
ADD [hasCodeMappingDefaults] BIT NULL
GO

ALTER TABLE [SIntegrationProvider]
ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_SIntegrationProvider_hasCodeMappingDefaults]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [hasCodeMappingDefaults]
GO

-- Set the new value for ENav
IF EXISTS(SELECT COLUMN_NAME
      FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
      WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'SIntegrationProvider'
             AND COLUMN_NAME = 'hasCodeMappingDefaults') 
UPDATE [SIntegrationProvider]
SET [hasCodeMappingDefaults] = 1
WHERE [provider] = 'EmployeeNavigator';
```

Comment: you are not solving the problem. you only put an error handling and avoid an error message. You set the default value to 1 so even without the update, all value of that column is 1

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean? It was my assumption that by the time it had got to the third part query that it hadn't fully committed the data. So by putting the IF EXISTS in there it would recompile and recognize that the column had been added and thus allow the UPDATE. Is that not correct?

Comment: if you get an error because the column do not exists, then the if clause is false and will not execute the update command. you put a code not to fix the root cause. the root cause is why the column is not found after alter table. Again you did not fix something. you fix your code not to return an error.